# Exact sequence $R_K^m→R_K^n→I→0$ given in Silverman's AAEC

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, elliptic-curves, exact-sequence

Let $R$ be Dedekind domain and $I$ be $R$'s fractional ideal.
Then my book (Advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves, written by Silvermn, p113) reads there exists resolution(exact sequence)

$R_K^m→R_K^n→I→0$ (The first arrow is producing $m×n$ matrices with coeffieints in $R_K$).

But for given $I$, how we take $m,n$ and why is this an exact sequence ?

Comment: $R$ is a noetherian ring, so $I$ is finitely presented (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_module#Finitely_presented,_finitely_related,_and_coherent_modules)

Comment: Think of the map $R^n_K\to I$ as a choice of generators, and the kernel $R^m_K\to R^n_K$ as the relations among those generators.

Comment: What exactly is the map $R_K^m→R_K^n$ and $R_K^n→I$ ?